# Intercept & reply to WSS requests in Electron

Tags: websocket, electron

The following code allows intercepting & replying to HTTPS requests in Electron :

```js
mainWindow.webContents.session.protocol.interceptBufferProtocol(
    'https',
    async (
        {
            url,
            method,
            uploadData: [{ bytes: requestPayload } = {}] = [],
            headers: requestHeaders
        },
        callback
    ) => {
        const {
            statusCode,
            headers: responseHeaders,
            payload: responsePayload
        } = await doSomething({
            url,
            headers: requestHeaders,
            method,
            payload: requestPayload
        });
        callback({
            statusCode,
            headers: responseHeaders,
            data: responsePayload
        });
    }
);
```

It doesn't require starting a server nor replacing renderer-side global variables like `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`.

What's the equivalent for WSS ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but look into protocol's documentation; it allows you to input a scheme, like https or http; perhaps it'll work for ws. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol

Comment: Passing `wss` as scheme (first) parameter of `interceptBufferProtocol` doesn't throw any error but doesn't fire the handler (second) parameter either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Conclusion:

- WebSocket requests can be captured. But you can't modify it.
- It is impossible to capture WebSocket requests via [electron/api/protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol) and [electron/api/web-request](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-request)

I went to the DevTools source code and found that DevTools can capture WebSocket messages because it does so via CDP(Chrome DevTools Protocol). See: [ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/front_end/core/sdk/NetworkManager.ts](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/1a9c7dc0b2e17137d6b91300c3371177f5235a3a/front_end/core/sdk/NetworkManager.ts#L783-L805).

So our task becomes clear, we just need to figure out how to communicate with CDP in electron, and we're done.

At first, I focused on the `extension API` because there is a [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/) API in the chrome extension API that helps us communicate with the CDP. However, unfortunately, `Electron` does not support the `debugger API` yet. See: [electron/api/extensions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/extensions).

So I spent some more time looking for other solutions and finally found this: [electron/api/debugger](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/debugger). Then the next thing is much simpler. Here is the core code

```js
const _debugger = mainWindow.webContents.debugger;
_debugger.attach();
_debugger.on('message', async (_event, method, params) => {
  if (method === 'Network.webSocketFrameReceived') {
    console.log('Received WebSocket info: ', JSON.stringify(params, null , 2));
  }
  
  if (method === 'Network.webSocketFrameSent') {
    console.log('Sent WebSocket info: ', JSON.stringify(params, null , 2));
  }
  
  if (method === 'Target.attachedToTarget') {
    // capture iframe websocket request
    if (params.targetInfo.type === "iframe") {
      await _debugger.sendCommand('Network.enable', null, params.sessionId);
      await _debugger.sendCommand('Runtime.enable', null, params.sessionId);
      await _debugger.sendCommand('Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger', null, params.sessionId);
    }
  }
});

mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
  _debugger.detach();
});

await _debugger.sendCommand("Network.enable");
await _debugger.sendCommand("Target.setAutoAttach", {
  autoAttach: true,
  waitForDebuggerOnStart: true,
  flatten: true
});
```

The full code is at: https://gist.github.com/2f88d43d7d4893b22e6a43f2b09bad3f. You can use https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle to run this program quickly.

As for why the WebSocket message cannot be modified, it seems to be a Chromium bug at the moment. See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1283412. Once chromium fixes this issue, it will be possible to modify the websocket message.

You can reproduce this error with the following code: https://gist.github.com/207ad63cf35681805551a98a39524a39

Comment: Thank you very much for your research. Would you also attach an approximate code snippet that may work once the bug is fixed ? Thanks again.

Comment: Until it is fixed, it is hard for me to guarantee that my code will be reliable. In fact, I compiled Electron locally the day before yesterday and made changes to the Chromium-related code, but frustratingly it didn't do the trick . I rechecked the relevant implementation and found that this is probably expected rather than a bug, and if Chromium were to fix it, it would probably be a feature, not a fix. 

Comment: Dang I was rather hoping I could use something like this to enable mTLS for a package that opens a websocket connection.